# Web API controller with two PUT methods throw an InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web Api 2.2 app with .NET Framework 4.5.1 and C#.

I have a controller with this method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(
    string productCode,
    byte codeLevel,
    string productionOrderName,
    string batchName,
    string lineName,
    int quantity)
{
```

And this is how I have configured its route on `WebApiConfig`:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ExternalCodesActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/ExternalCodes/{action}/{productCode}/{codeLevel}/{productionOrderName}/{batchName}/{lineName}/{quantity}",
    defaults: new { controller = "ExternalCodes" });
```

But now I have another method on the same controller (`ExternalCodesController`):

```
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage SetCodesAsUsed(List<string> codes)
{
```

But, with that route, when I put to that method (**http://myHost:53827/api/ExternalCodes/SetCodesAsUsed**), I get an `InvalidOperationException` with the message:

> "Several actions that matched the request were found: 
>   SetCodesAsUsed in type
>   MyProject.Web.API.Controllers.ExternalCodesController
>   SetCodesAsUnUsed in type
>   MyProject.Web.API.Controllers.ExternalCodesController",

There is also another method in the same `ExternalCodesController`:

```
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage SetCodesAsUnUsed(List<string> codes)
{
```

What am I doing wrong?

The methods have different names.

Comment: I doubt that the conflict is because these Web API operations...

Comment: _"when I put to that method"_ - show the request.

Comment: This can help you, http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The web api doesn't pay much attention to method names - it just see's two PUT's with the same signature.

[Web API 2 Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) is the most convenient solution to this issue as it makes it easy to mix  RPC calls in a RESTful API

eg:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("api/ExternalCodes/SetCodesAsUnUsed")]
public HttpResponseMessage SetCodesAsUnUsed(List<string> codes)

[HttpPut]
[Route("api/ExternalCodes/SetCodesAsUsed")]
public HttpResponseMessage SetCodesAsUsed(List<string> codes)
```

Comment: The route templates in this answr doesn't follow the recommended Resource Naming for RESTful Web API. 
(read: http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html )  Is there a better approach?

Comment: According to your link's definition I think you might need to have two controllers, each with one PUT? eg: PUT /api/UnsedExternalCodes and PUT /api/UsedExternalCodes.

Comment: Just the answer i needed.